# Can we get a gay-rights tag?

Tags: feature-request

I tried to make a [gay-rights](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gay-rights) tag on my [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8000/why-do-people-say-the-indiana-religious-freedom-act-will-be-used-to-discriminate), but I don't have enough rep yet. I think it fits well with my question and would be useful on the site.

Comment: i've added one.

Comment: There is a record for a tag edit for the question, but the tag disappeared with no record of its removal. The [lgbt+] tag was added.

Answer (score -2):

We already have the [lgbt+](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt%2b) tag, which should work for your purposes, as lgbt+ includes gay.

Comment: This question was asked and the tag was added over 6 years ago and in fact it no longer has that tag anyway.

Comment: @JoeW sure, but I figured that just in case anybody stumbled upon this question in the future there’s a chance my answer would be helpful

Comment: I am not sure that matters as people are likely to find the lgbt+ tag or if they have tag creation privilege's just create the gay-rights tag. It has been over 6 years since this was asked and no one has asked for it since then and I don't think it it likely that anyone will ask for it soon.